# Npm errors on any command

Tags: node.js, npm

So I tried installing any npm package or npm itself but I keep getting this error

```
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","
arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

I am in windows 7.
I use node v8.9.4 and npm v.5.6.0. I also have installed git.
Is there anything I can do to debug my npm.

I tried `npm cache verify` and `npm cache clean -f` but none worked.

Comment: let try `npm i -f`

Comment: I think it worked! Though I now get `node-gyp rebuild` when trying to install canvas (what I wanted) fortunately I dont get the other error anymore. Would you like to post that as an answer.

Comment: It's good to see it worked. My instruction is from my old experience (I met this issue before), I cannot explain it, so I cannot put it as an answer :D. Don't worry. Thanks for your kindness.

Answer (score 0):

You should re-do your NodeJS instalation, maybe you clicked on something you should when it asked you about your command line.